# optical flow on feature detected points

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, feature-detection

Background:

im working on a project for school. I have a raspberry pi, a small RC car and a camera. My task is to follow a path (line on the ground) and avoid obstacles based on computer vision. So far I can track the line and follow it.

Now I want to avoid obstacles and I have two ideas:

First idea:

1.) Detect features with surf in two images
2.) Calculate optical flow of the features 
3.) Use CNN or Tensorflow with the calculated optical flow to avoid obstacles

Second idea:

1.) Detect features with surf in two images
2.) Calculate the fundamental matrix
3.) use eipolar geometry to calculate the distance of a feature relative to the camera

I think the first approach makes sense.
This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import time

cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 1000,1000)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)


#create surf
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
cv2.xfeatures2d.hessianThreshold = 50000


#get features from first frame
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_frame = cv2.flip(old_frame,1)
old_kp, old_dp = surf.detectAndCompute(old_frame, None)





while(True):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, new_frame = cap.read()
    new_frame = cv2.flip(new_frame,1)

    new_kp, new_dp = surf.detectAndCompute(new_frame, None)



    if len(new_kp) > 2 and len(old_kp) != 2:
        #match
        matches = flann.knnMatch(old_dp,new_dp,k=2)


        matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(matches), 0, -1)]
        # ratio test as per Lowe's paper
        for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
            if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                matchesMask[i]=[1,0]


        draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), singlePointColor = (255,0,0),matchesMask = matchesMask,flags = 0)


        result = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(old_frame,old_kp,new_frame,new_kp,matches,None,**draw_params)




    old_frame = new_frame
    old_kp = new_kp
    old_dp = new_dp

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('image',result)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can detect features but I don't know how to calculate the optical flow of these points.
I tried to use the cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() function in openCV but this does not work for me.

My questions:

Are my ideas/approaches correct? Is it possible to avoid obstacles in this way?

How can I calculate the optical flow for my surf keypoins?

Thanks in advance